# How to use PHP to display multiple single cells from mysql database using another cell in the same row as an index or reference

Tags: php, arrays, indexing

I'm an interaction designer building out front_end HTML design. I am new to PHP, but old hand with HTML and quick to new technology. I'm hoping someone can help me out. I've done a few hours of research and can't find the answer to in any forum so far to my very specific problem.

**GOAL:** I'd like a nice way to display various discrete cells of data from my database into my HTML designs. Specifically, I'd like to be able to display a given 'title' on my page design by referencing a unique id in the same row of the database. Here's what one row looks like...

'unique_id'
'title'
'description'
'image'

What I need is a simple way to pull individual cells from an array using some small code snippet. Something like this:

```
<li class="active"><a href="#"><?php echo [unique_id][title];?></a></li>
```

...where unique_id would work as an index that would tell the array which row to look at, and then display the title from that same row.

I have a hunch it has to do with indexed arrays and some special loops, but I am very lost. Your help, but more importantly teaching me so I can learn, would be most appreciated.

Here's what I have currently, but it doesn't work because it's only going off the incremental row order (0..., 1..., 2...). What I need is for those numbers to be unique_ids for the rows, like (1005..., 104..., 106...).

```
<?php
                $sql = "SELECT title FROM phones";
                $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
                $array = array();

                while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                $array[] = $row;
            }
            ?>

            <ul class="nav nav-list">
              <li class="nav-header">iOS Phones</li>
              <li class="active"><a href="#"><?php echo $array[0][title];?></a></li>
              <li><a href="#"><?php echo $array[1][title]?></a></li>
```

Christopher

Comment: You should move your `HTML` code into your `while` loop.

Comment: Good exposition for a first-time poster but could you clarify what you want by adding some HTML as it would be outputted if everything worked correctly?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you wish to list the titles along with their unique ID's?

It can be achieved using MySQL & PHP like this:

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM phones";
$result = mysqli_query($sql);

echo "<ul>";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 
  echo "<li><a href='#'>" . $row["unique_id"] . " - " . $row["title"] . "</a></li>";
}
echo "</ul>";
?>
```

This will output something like this:

```
<ul>
<li><a href='#'>100 - HelloWorld</a></li>
<li><a href='#'>101 - AnotherTitle</a></li>
</ul>
```

And so forth.. You can order the outputs alphabetically by title or by the unique ID's. This can be done by adding `ORDER BY title` or `ORDER BY unique_id` to the end of your `$sql` variable.

What it does is just loop through all the database entries received from `SELECT * FROM phones`. Every row will be put into a `$row` array.

I hope this helped a bit.